# Abstract class in Java - creating methods

Tags: java, oop, object, abstract-class, abstract

I have a question about abstract classes in Java.
I have created abstract class like this:

```
public class userClass {
private String email;
String accountType;
account account;

public userClass(String email, String accountType){
    this.setEmail(email);
    this.setAccountType(accountType);

     if(accountType.equals("basic")){
          this.account = new basicAccount();
     } 
     else if(accountType.equals("premium")){
          this.account = new premiumAccount();
     }
}
```

As you see I have accounts of two types: basic and premium, they are both extensions of account abstract class. Now I would like to add method only to premium class, but when I'm trying to do so, I receive an error saying that I have to implement it in account class, which I don't want. Is it possible to do it in other way? To avoid putting empty method in account and basicAccount classes?

Comment: The class isn't `abstract`... Did you post the right code?

Comment: There is no reason you can't add a method to one extension of an abstract class but not in the base class. Please post the actual code that is giving you an error for more help.

Comment: please add definition of `account ` Class.

Comment: The account class is an abstract class. 

I would like to create method for account.shareFile(fileReceiver,fileName); but I don't want to have that method in basic account, because my assumption is that this sharing is not allowed for basic accounts.

Comment: @gariaable please post the code that is actually giving you the error. Without that, there is nothing more we can really do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you if you have an `Account` class like:

```
public abstract class Account{
    public abstract void doSomethingAccountLike();
    //more stuff
}
```

You can have child classes:

```
public class BasicAccount extends Account{
    public void doSomethingAccountLike(){
        //implementation specific to basic accounts
    }
}

public class PremiumAccount extends Account{
    public void doSomethingAccountLike(){
        //implementation specific to premium accounts
    }

    public void doSomethingPremiumLike(){
        //something that only makes sense
        // in the context of a premium account
    }
}
```

The method `doSomethingPremiumLike()` is only available when you have an instance of a `PremiumAccount` i.e.:

```
public class AccountDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        PremiumAccount premium = new PremiumAccount();
        BasicAccount basic = new BasicAccount();
        Account generalAccount = premium;

        //valid- the compiler knows that the
        //premium object is an instance of the
        //premium class
        premium.doSomethingPremiumLike();

        //Would cause a compile error if uncommented.
        //The compiler knows that basic is an instance
        //of a BasicAccount, for which the method
        //doSomethingPremiumLike() is undefined.
        //basic.doSomethingPremiumLike();

        //Would generate a compiler error if uncommented.
        //Even though generalAccount actually refers to
        //an object which is specifically a PremiumAccount,
        //the compiler only knows that it has a reference to
        //an Account object, it doesn't know that it's actually
        //specifically a PremiumAccount. Since the method
        // doSomethingPremiumLike() is not defined for a general
        //Account, this won't compile
        //generalAccount.doSomethingPremiumLike();

        //All compile- all are instances of Account
        //objects, and the method doSomethingAccountLike()
        //is defined for all accounts.
        basic.doSomethingAccountLike();
        premium.doSomethingAccountLike();
        generalAccount.doSomethingAccountLike();
    }
}
```

**Your issue**

It sounds to me like your issue is likely that in the class `UserClass`, you have a field `Account account`. In your constructor, you assign either a `new BasicAccount()` or a `new PremiumAccount()` to the field `account`. This is perfectly fine, but once you do that, *the compiler no longer knows in any given case whether the `account` field refers to a `PremiumAccount` instance or a `BasicInstance`.* This means that if you try to call `account.doSomethingPremiumLike()`, you will get a compiler error. You can get around this restriction at runtime:

In `UserClass` somewhere:

```
if(account instanceof PremiumAccount){
    //if we're sure that account is actually a PremiumAccount,
    //cast it to a PremiumAccount here to let the compiler know
    //that doSomethingPremiumLike() can be called 
   ((PremiumAccount)account).doSomethingPremiumLike();
}
```

---

Note: I have changed the names of your classes to start with upper case letters as is the common convention in Java and most other OOP languages. It's good to get in the habit of following this convention to help others read your code.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's how it looks like, but in my code, when I create object, I do this using account newAccount = new basicAccount(); and because of that I receive an error saying that I have to put this new method doSomethingPremiumLike() also inside of account abstract method (and what follows in basicAccount, which I would like to avoid)

Comment: You should creat it the other way round - BasicAccount account = new PremiumAccount(). And then cast account variable to PremiumAccount if you want to use some specific method.

Comment: But is possible to create object in this way? Eclipse shows me that to create new object of premiumAccount(), it has to be like 'account account' or 'basicAccount accont'

Comment: It's perfect now! Thank You a lot!

Comment: @gariaable: I believe I see where your issue is. See the stuff I just added after *Your Issue*

Comment: This question got me thinking of yet another question, I got some nice replies (see the comments section along with answer). The question may be useful to see some other aspects of the issue we have here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376979/should-concrete-implementation-provide-any-public-api-not-present-in-the-interfa